# double free or corruption while deleting an object

Tags: c++, destructor, glibc

I have a class named "Packet" with this destruct:

```
class Packet
{
   ...
   RequestPtr req;
   ~Packet()
   {
     if (req && isRequest() && !needsResponse())
        delete req;      
     deleteData();
   }
};
```

The RequestPtr looks like:

```
typedef Request* RequestPtr;
class Request
{
   ...
   ~Request() {} 
}
```

Problem is when `delete req;` and consequently `~Request() {}` are executed, I get this error:

```
*** glibc detected *** double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000002a8a640 ***
```

At first I thought that maybe `req` were deleted somewhere else and when it want to execute `delete req;`, obviously there is no `req`. However as you can see, there is a `if` statement which checks if the `req` is defined or not. So definitely when it want to delete `req`, the object is defined.

What does this error really mean?

Comment: All `if (req)` tests is whether `req` is null or not. If it's already been freed, or points to a random (unitialized for instance) memory location, that test will pass.

Comment: if `req` is freed, then I think it is null so `if (req)` should fail. Isn't it? what is the different between deleted object and null?

Comment: No, freeing req doesn't make it become null. You have to do that yourself if you want that behavior. `free req` has no effect on the `req` pointer itself, only on what it points to (_if_ it points to a valid, live object of the right type).

Comment: No, you must set `req` to NULL after `delete`. `delete` does do this for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default copy constructor and assignment operator are used in class `Packet` and you have a pointer to dynamically allocated memory.

If a copy of `Packet` is made and the original object destroyed a double deallocation will occur when the second object is destroyed. Either implement the copy constructor and assignment operator or prevent copying of `Packet` by declaring them `private`.

The check `if (req)` will be true if `req` is not NULL, not if it has already been deallocated (as stated by Mat in comment to question).

If you `delete req` in some other method of the class you must set `req` to NULL:

```
delete req;
req = 0;
```

Or a double deallocation will occur.

Just to note that calling `delete` on a NULL pointer has no effect, so the following is safe:

```
delete req;
req = 0;
delete req; // No need to check 'if (req)'
```

Comment: or use shared_ptr

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to delete is

```
delete req;
req = 0;
```

otherwise `req` will be a dangling pointer after deletion.

Comment: That's really bad advice. Among other problems, it generates a mindset that breaks horribly if two pointers ever point to the same object.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Why is this bad advice? Did this post get edited or am I missing something?

Comment: It's bad advice because it generates the mindset that if a pointer's value is not NULL, it points to something valid. If you want that behavior in C++, you should create a class that implements it, not try to pair `delete` operations with `NULL`s. That's just atrocious style and leads to more confusion about how pointers work. (And it breaks horribly as soon as two pointers point to the same object.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Ok, I get your point. Your first comment wasn't really clear. Cheers.

Comment: It also does nothing to solve this exact problem which was caused by the OP having two pointers to the same object and then calling `delete` on both of them. (In fact, it encourages this problem.)

Answer (score -1):

I use this macro in classes that are responsible for cleaning up other objects:

```
// place in a commonly included .h file of yours

#define SAFE_DELETE(p) \
 {if (p != NULL) \
     delete p;\
 p = NULL;}
```

usage in cpp file:

```
~Packet() {
    SAFE_DELETE(req)
}
```

It checks if the pointer is non-NULL, deletes pointer if so, and sets it to NULL so that the same thing doesn't happen again.

Comment: The `if (p != NULL)` is useless since `delete`-ing a NULL pointer is valid.

Comment: @Cicada You're right on my Windows system today. Maybe when I first started using this macro it was necessary. Did heap managers crash on the 'delete NULL' in older times? I would still use the macro without the if so that the pointer was set to NULL.

Comment: As far as I remember `delete`-ing NULL has always been legal, even back to C where `free(NULL)` works like a charm.

Comment: Wait a sec. Isn't it less expensive to check for NULL rather than making the function call to delete?

Comment: This is bad advice for a variety of reasons. Among other things, it accomplishes absolutely nothing in the example usage -- the variable is set to NULL right before it ceases to exist anyway. (It's also the most ridiculously unsafe thing in the world. Consider `SAFE_DELETE(list->getHeadItem());`. Cool, we delete the head item and then set the **new** head item to NULL?!)

Comment: @David Thats really unsafe usage. I would say don't use it with the a function call, just with variables. I don't get why you think it accomplished nothing in the posters problem.

Comment: @ScrollerBlaster It would accomplish nothing in the OP's case because his problem was that he had two pointers that pointed to the same object and deleted both of them. Calling `delete` on one of those pointers and then setting it to NULL would leave him the exact same problem when he called `delete` on the other pointer. The pointer he passed to `delete` was about to go away itself anyway. Setting it to NULL accomplishes *nothing*.

Comment: @David Indeed. In that case if the object is being pointed to from multiple independant locations and we don't know which of these has the ultimate responsibility to delete the Request instance, he could make the Request class a reference counted object. addRef() and release() methods... Thats what we did back in the day. I have a SAFE_RELEASE macro for such classes also (which I would continue to use) !

Comment: @ScrollerBlaster Exactly. The ultimate answer is to avoid C-style pointers unless you have a good reason to use them (that is, they happen to be exactly what you want/need). There are all kinds of smart pointers, safe pointers, reference-counted pointers, and the like. You can choose a pointer that has exactly the behavior you want.